# Why is my dSLR's pop-up flash not firing?

Tags: nikon, flash, dslr

I have a Nikon D3200 and the flash is not working. It used to work, but it just stopped suddenly.

I've tried everything (resetting setup options and shooting menu etc. etc.) But still it's not working. I've tried removing the flash cap and I see no switch on the right side. Flash is popping up but the flash is not firing.

Comment: Did it ever work? Did it just suddenly stop?

Comment: Yes it worked but it suddenly stopped idk why

Answer (score 2):

There is a "no flash" position of the rotary mode knob, but the flash is supposed to fire if it pops up.  So it sounds like a defect, and probably needs Nikon service.

Comment: Do you know what has happend to ny dslr? Because it was working before and it suddenly stopped..

Answer (score 1):

Since you've checked for any microswitch jamming (assume you've also cleaned the hotshoe) and done settings/mode resets on the camera, I think it's probably a hardware issue.

Googling around, it looks like there is a construction inside Nikon pop-up flashes that can get misaligned/broken so that either the pop-up won't pop up or won't fire when it's popped up, because the proper contact isn't made. A small plastic tab holding tension on one arm tends to break or dislodge. This may not be your problem (could also be a burned out bulb, bad capacitor, etc.) But fixes for the D70 look like they require partial disassembly of the pop-up flash and then either [repositioning the tab](https://photorojo.blogspot.com/2010/02/nikon-d70-dslr-flash-fix.html), or [jury-rigging up a replacement with a toothpick and superglue](https://www.tutorialgeek.net/2010/11/fix-flash-on-nikon-d70-dslr.html).

Obviously, if you are not good with electronics and diagnosing hardware issues, I'd recommend sending it in for service, rather than risking getting zapped (even pop-up flashes have capacitors) or breaking your camera.  But if this is a second body, you own your own soldering equipment and a multimeter, and you love tearing things apart and putting them back together (not uncommon on Stackexchange), maybe these fixes are for you.